# online plan draw software/scripts

Tags: web-apps, javascript, php, flash

I want to install a online architectural plan drawing software on my website like the link provided below, it will be used by my customers to draw a plan and send me to draw a proper autoCAD drawing and construct the house. I found following is very simple to use and has many features like furniture and both 2d and 3d options. So can someone direct me to a script/software that can be implemented on my website? paid or free ones are ok.

http://planner.roomsketcher.com/

#### The requirements

1. It should be able to draw a 2D plan and be able to take snapshots in 3D and view in builtin 3D viewer.
2. It can be any script/software/flash
3. It can be a free software or the price is under US$500
4. The users should be able to insert components like doors, windows, wall colours, floor textures (wood, tiles, granite, rock finishes etc), tables, kitchen items, staircases etc.
5. It should be able to draw in multiple levels, such as 1st floor, 2nd floor etc
6. It's better if it can draw roof etc also, but it's optional
7. The users should be able to save the plan with dimensions (length in feet or meters preferably)
8. The textures in 3D rendering should be in reasonably good quality (the quality in the provided link or better quality)

Recommendations for free software are most welcome. Our current budget would allow for about USD 500 at max – but we *might* be able to increase that for something really good.

Comment: Glad to see it suits you :) Cleaning up comments then. Unfortunately I don't know such a software – but with the details you've now provided, it should be possible to give good recommendations. Fingers crossed!